# spring boot security login error 400, using Guava Optional instead of Java 8 Optional

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I try to add spring security to my webapp. I've found this tuto : [spring boot security application](http://kielczewski.eu/2014/12/spring-boot-security-application/). But I get an error 400 on my login page.

Here is the code of my security config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/bus/topologie", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/bus/login")
                .failureUrl("/bus/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/bus/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my controller, when using Java 7 optional instead of Java 8 Optional, the request dispatcher doesn't find it :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bus/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@RequestParam Optional<String> error) {
        LOGGER.debug("Getting login page, error={}", error);
        return new ModelAndView("login", "error", error);
    }

}
```

And the code of the application.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

                ErrorPage error400Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "/400.html");
                ErrorPage error401Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/401.html");
                ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404.html");
                ErrorPage error500Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500.html");

                container.addErrorPages(error401Page, error404Page, error500Page, error400Page);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

The login.html page is almost empty.

Edit : I've found a good lead, but I don't know how to correct it. When I remove the attribute `@RequestParam Optional<String> error`, everything works fine. But I need to handle the error. I'm working with java 7, using guava optional instead of java 8 java.util.Optional. What is the good way to do this in java 7?

Comment: what do you have in the catalina output? or any other log apart of the bad request return?

Comment: I've nothing in the console. I don't really know where to look at in order to have more info. If I put a wrong url in the browser, like [context-path]/bus/tata, I have the same problem.

Comment: do you run this app by java -jar yourfile.jar ? then stay looking on that console, it should throw something more specific

Comment: best way to debug is to check your inspect element network request,it would should what all you sent and on what request it failed.Also,could you attach those details as well.Thanks.

Comment: Also,along with the above,kindly attach your failed request controller details.Thanks.

Comment: @jpganz18 : I use application.java > debug as > spring boot app. I've added the debug output in the question content

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is because you are requesting a param that you are not getting all times... you have two options.

Ensure you always send that param.

Make it not required.

If you want to make it not required you can do something like this

```
@RequestParam((value = "error", required=false)String error)
```